# How to combine these 2 fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have total Count of comments  for 1 movie

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=object_id).count()
```

How to Count all comments in time period `(start_date,end_date)`
I know About Q filter `filter=Q(Comments__pub_date__range=( start_date, end_date))`

so, how compine those two Fields and get the answer??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to count all comments for movie with id `object_id`.So you filter comments on pub date like this:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(movie_id = object_id, pub_date__range = (start_date, end_date) ).count()
```